# Azure Time Series Insights Gen2 Cold store missing data

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I have an Azure TSI environment, it has a 7 days warm store.
But recently a discovered difference in cold and warm store data points. It's not a matter of delay, because the data is permanently missing.

Could there be a problem what the storageaccount, what metrics can I inspect to confirm this?

I do see "ClientOtherErrors", but dont know if they are cause by TSI ingestion.

[image]

[image]

Should I look at memory usage?

Comment: Hello @Hubert if you select this same period now, do you still see that discrepancy in your cold store? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed using Customer Support Service, this issue was caused due two mistakes:

- Blob manipulation.
- Hub recreation with the same name and higher number of partitions, without recreating the TSI event source.

After recreating the TSI Event Source, the issue was fixed.